# chrome.browserAction.setPopup() - local html files only?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to modify my extension's popup dynamically (at run-time). And want to specify a custom popup HTML file that's loaded from my server.

In Firefox, I can easily accomplish this with [XUL overlays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Overlays#Loading_Overlays_at_Run-time) which I can specify at run-time.
And [document.loadOverlay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.loadOverlay)  does allow me to specify a **'remote' URL for the overlay**.

Is the same possible in Chrome?

I've been playing with [chrome.browserAction.setPopup( details ) API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup), but it seems that the `details.popup` **param must specify a local file, and not a remote URL**.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this exact same question on the [Chromium-Extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/EAOtub-QBaI/EIv6_LRZSfAJ) mailinglist.

There is no API to load external popups but you can do that with plain JavaScript. What you could do (I have done that in the past):

- Use an iframe + extension messaging within the popup. The iframe
  points to some external url not hosted in the extension.
- Use templates (jQuery templates example), load those template files to
  your background page, and just use them to construct your popup.
- Download the html contents using XHR and load them within the popup
  by constructing the DOM.

I usually use the template approach, but I use the popup iframe approach when I want to manage the entire popup in the server side so I don't have to push updates to the extension gallery. I am not a fan of downloading the HTML contents, templating seems safer.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Could you add a link to the mailinglist archive with the mentioned post?

Comment: @Tobo, I updated the post and added the link to the mentioned article.